# Find Laplace transform of $(sin^2 2t)$

Tags: laplace-transform

Find Laplace transform of $(\sin^2 2t)$

How do I go about this ?

do I spilt them up like

$ L ( \sin 2t) \cdot L (\sin 2t) $ ?

Comment: No, you can't do that. Use that $\sin^2(2t) = \frac{1-\cos(4t)}{2}$

Comment: Also note that multiplication on time domain becomes convolution on Laplace domain.

Answer (score 1):

No!  The Laplace transform of fg is NOT L(f)L(g).  Instead use the basic definition: $\int_0^\infty sin^2(2t)e^{-st}dt$.  You might find it simplest to use the fact that $sin(x)= \frac{e^{ix}- e^{-ix}}{2i}$ so that $sin(2t)= \frac{e^{2it}- e^{-2it}}{2i}$ and $sin^2(2t)= \left(\frac{e^{2it}- e^{-2it}}{2i}\right)^2= -\frac{e^{4it}- 2+ e^{-4it}}{4}$.

Comment: We can use the convolution property too, right?

Answer (score 1):

Given $\sin^22t$

$$\sin^22t=\dfrac{1-\cos4t}{2}$$
$$L(\sin^22t)=\dfrac{L(1)-L(\cos4t)}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2s}-\dfrac12\left(\dfrac{s}{s^2+16}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$\sin^2 2t= \dfrac{1-\cos 4t}{2}$$

Comment: How did you get this ?

Comment: @user185692 you can use $ \cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = 1$ and  $\cos (a+b)=\cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b$